# jquery rotate max count

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, rotateanimation, jquery-rotate

I have read through countless SO posts and have made numerous attempts, but a whole afternoon later I am still stuck.

My code, combined with the jquery plugin that I am using can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mf6xed3w/) at this jsfiddle

**What am I trying to do?**

For this project I am making a call to the iTunes API, which provides me with a list of songs by a named artist. I am then storing these mp4a files ([one example](http://a1654.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/022/Music/v4/06/a1/0c/06a10c8b-e358-4bc0-c443-a120a775d3df/mzaf_1439207983024487820.plus.aac.p.m4a)) in an array, and each time the record image is clicked (see jsfiddle) the next song/item in the array is played. Each of these snippets is 30 seconds. This works fine.

**Jquery Issues**

I am using the jquery animation plugin to spin the record image for 30 seconds as that is the length each song. This works fine with the code below/jsfiddle if I click the record once and only play one song. However, if I click on the record to play the next song a new 30 seconds is added on each click. Again, this is no problem if I wait until the end of a song, but if I click, lets say, three times, all of sudden 90 seconds are added to the animation length.

Is anyone able to help so that I can ensure that the count cannot be greater than 30? I have tried all sorts of if/else statements, but disappointingly cannot crack it. Also, I have gone through the jquery rotate plugin code with a fine toothcomb, and tried change some of the code in there, but also to no avail.

Currently my jquery code is as follows, which is combined with the plugin code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#btn').click(function(){
           $(this).rotate({ count:30, forceJS:true });                  
      });
  });
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.entertainmentayr.com/joey_Lawrence_files/entertayr%20gold%20record%20LP%20logo%20small%20.png" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's built in [`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop the animation before you start a new one using the `rotate` plugin. Setting `clearQueue` to `true` will prevent any extra animations from being run after stopping the current one, and setting `jumpToEnd` will prevent it from starting the animation mid-stream. Without `jumpToEnd` it will still try to take a full second to do whatever is left in the rotation, which will look weird if you click just before it finishes the rotation - try experimenting with this turned on or off to see the difference.

```js
$(this).stop(true, true).rotate({ count: 30, forceJS: true });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mf6xed3w/1/

Answer (score 2):

I hope I got it right: you need a `.stop()` call on your animation. This way, every `click` will start a new song and a new animation for you. 
Here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mf6xed3w/2/ with duration changed to 3 seconds so you can see the result easier.